# iOS : How to activate image stabilization on an AVCaptureSession?

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession, ios-camera

I'd like to capture stabilized images in my app but I haven't found the required configuration to acheive it.

This is my code :

```
let frontCamera = cameraWithPosition(AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front)

let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

if captureSession.canSetSessionPreset(AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto) {
    captureSession.sessionPreset =  AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto 
    print("Session preset has been set ")
}
else {
    print("Session preset couldn't be set ")
}

var error: NSError?
var input: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
do {
    input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: frontCamera)
} catch let error1 as NSError {
    error = error1
    input = nil
}

if error == nil && captureSession!.canAddInput(input) {
    captureSession.addInput(input)
    let stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
    stillImageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]
    if stillImageOutput.stillImageStabilizationSupported {
        stillImageOutput.automaticallyEnablesStillImageStabilizationWhenAvailable = true
        print("Stabilization supported ")
    }
    else {
        print("Stabilization is not supported ")
    }
}
```

So the session preset are correctly set but the image stabilization is not supported.

What can I do to support image stabilisation ?

---

** **2nd ATTEMPT AFTER RHYTHMIC FISTMAN RESPONSE :** **

I switched to the back camera, I've added the output to the captureSession before setting it, and I still don't have my image stabilized :

```
    let backCamera = cameraWithPosition(AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back)

    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    if captureSession.canSetSessionPreset(AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto) {
        captureSession.sessionPreset =  AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto 
        print("Session preset has been set ")
    }
    else {
        print("Session preset couldn't be set ")
    }


    var error: NSError?
    var input: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
    do {
        input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)
    } catch let error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
        input = nil
    }

    if error == nil && captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
        captureSession.addInput(input)
        let stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
        stillImageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]


        if captureSession.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
            captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)

            if stillImageOutput.stillImageStabilizationSupported == true {
                stillImageOutput.automaticallyEnablesStillImageStabilizationWhenAvailable = true
                print("Stabilization supported ")
            }
            else {
                print("Stabilization is not supported ")
            }

            if stillImageOutput.stillImageStabilizationActive == true {
                print("Stabilization is active ")
            }
            else {
                print("Stabilization is not active ")
            }
        }
    }
```

The result is :
Stabilization is not supported
Stabilization is not active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you've forgotten to add your `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` to the `AVCaptureSession`. You must do that before querying its capabilities!

```
captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
```

Secondly, [neither Digital nor Optical Image Stabilisation are supported on the front camera](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2409/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40015038-CH1-OPTICAL_IMAGE_STABILIZATION).

Thirdly, on the back camera, on supported platforms (digital appears to be available on 5S up) `AVCaptureStillImageOutput automaticallyEnablesStillImageStabilizationWhenAvailable` defaults to `YES`, so if you switch to the back camera - then you already *will* be using some form of image stabilisation.

NB: Optical Image Stabilisation [is only available on the 6+ and 6S+](http://www.apple.com/au/iphone-6s/cameras/) (although the linked technote has not been updated for the 6S models yet).

Comment: I followed your recommandations and it's still not working.  (I edited the question)

Comment: I'm running it on iPhone 5

Comment: Digital stabilisation is available on 5S and up

Comment: Did that answer your question?

Comment: Hi @RhythmicFistman Thanks for sharing your knowledge. Do you happen to know the answer to our related question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34912050/avoiding-blurriness-at-start-end-of-video-even-after-using-setpreferredvideos. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I'm on an iPhone 7 and stabilization will not activate regardless of what I try.